# Не сохраняются запись в SharedPreferences после повторного открытия приложения

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Вот так выглядит хелпер

```
public class MyPrefs {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    private final String APPS = "apps";

    private static MyPrefs instanse;

    private SharedPreferences mPref;

    public static MyPrefs getInstanse() {
        if (null != instanse) {
            return instanse;
        }
        return new MyPrefs();
    }

    private MyPrefs() {
        mPref = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    //App's settings
    public void addApp(String appName){
        HashSet<String> apps = getBootApps();
        apps.add(appName);
        addAllBootApps(apps);
    }

    public void addAllApps(HashSet<String> apps){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();
        editor.putStringSet(APPS, apps);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public HashSet<String> getApps(){
        return (HashSet<String>) mPref.getStringSet(APPS,new HashSet<String>());
    }

    public void deleteApp(String appName){
        HashSet<String> apps = getApps();
        apps.remove(appName);
        addAllApps(apps);
    }

    public void removewAllApps(){
        addAllApps(new HashSet<String>());
    }
}
```

с его помощью я сначала записываю через `addApp()` и сразу же вывожу содержимое с помощью `getApps()` и все изменения видны, но после рестарта приложения там ничего нету, при этом я использую одни и те же методы.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был решен, добавил строчку  `editor.clear()` в метод:

```
public void addAllBootApps(HashSet<String> apps){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putStringSet(APPS, apps);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Причина по которой все заработало мне все равно не ясна. Вот реф на [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837540/5634351) который мне помог.

P.S. если кто то может обьяснить, почему это сработало, был бы благодарен!?

Comment: Мб накопилось куча всего в префе? вот и помогает очистка прошлых данных перед тем как засунуть туда запись)

Comment: ну да, есть еще места в коде где я использую SP, но их всего пара мест таких.